Interface is not loading correctly in my ionic app when changing between pages
I'm using Ionic 7 Standalone components version with angular and I’m working with pages like login, register and landing. I’ve just added this leaftlet map library to show it in the background of some interfaces and since then it seems like that feature is affecting the interfaces rendering. In the other pages I’m not viewing this problem because i didn’t apply that feature.
For example, when I first click into the button or link that redirects me to the other page, the URL doesn't change and it shows half of the other page, the URL only changes when I double click on it and still doesn't even show the interface correctly, I have to refresh it to have the desired view. I would appreciate if someone can help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advanced!
I'm don't think if the problem involve the routes because if I remove the map feature from one of the pages using it then the page loads instantly but It's crucial for me to have it in my app.
